# Sharing messages between kafkacat consumers

Tags: apache-kafka

This is pretty much the same question as this: [Messages sent to all consumers with the same consumer group name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809636/messages-sent-to-all-consumers-with-the-same-consumer-group-name). The accepted answer is to use Kafka 0.8.1 or newer, which I did.

[Kafka documentation says](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#intro_consumers):

> If all the consumer instances have the same consumer group, then this works just like a traditional queue balancing load over the consumers.

But I am not able to observe this behaviour using Kafka 0.8.2.1 and [kafkacat](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat).

My setup:

- Kafka + Zookeeper running in [spotify/kafka](https://github.com/spotify/docker-kafka) container (via boot2docker)
- One producer
- Two consumers with the same group.id

First, in running Kafka container, I created a topic:

```
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --topic beta
```

Two consumers subscribed to same topic:

```
kafkacat -C -b $(boot2docker ip):9092 -t beta -X group.id=mygroup
```

Then I produce a message using kafkacat:

```
date | kafkacat -P -b $(boot2docker ip):9092 -t beta
```

I expect that only one consumer receives the message, but actually both of them do. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: When I try to run the same consumers using `kafka-console-consumer.sh`, all is fine:

```
echo "group.id=mygroupid" > /consumer.beta.properties

$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh \
  --zookeeper localhost:2181 \
  --topic beta \
  --consumer.config /consumer.beta.properties
```

All works as expected: the message is only consumed once. I assume the issue lies with kafkacat.

Comment: Balanced consumer groups are currently only supported through the use of Zookeeper, something that only the official Java/Scala consumers implement. But starting with Apache Kafka 0.9 (which is due in november 2015) there will be support for broker based consumer groups. This will also be supported in librdkafka and kafkacat by then.

Answer (score 3):

kafkacat now supports the 0.9 high-level KafkaConsumer:

`kafkacat -b <broker> -G <groupid> topic1 topic2..`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this feature [is not supported by librdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/152) (the library that kafkacat is using). Quoting from the [Github issue](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat/issues/48#issuecomment-143231322):

> Short answer, this is not supported for now. Also, whatever you see in the Kafka documentation is only true if you're using the JVM consumer/producer. Assume that any other consumer/producer implementation is not entirely following the doc.

Comment: judging from newer discussion at https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat/issues/139#issuecomment-704120456 this should be supported now (not sure about the -b but I see the -G one)